# Flutter fetch a webpage with user-agent parameter

Tags: http, flutter, dart, httprequest

I am using flutter http package for fetch a webpage.
I want to send http request like desktop.How can I do that ?

My User-Agent : `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"`

my code ;

```
  String text="mert";
  var isLoading = false;



 _fetchData() async {


final response =
    await http.get("http://trscript.net");
if (response.statusCode == 200) {

 var document = parse(response.body.toString());
 if(document.querySelector("body > div > div.sol.yaklas > div:nth-child(1) > article > div.yazi_bilgi")!=null){
    text = document.querySelector("body > div > div.sol.yaklas > div:nth-child(1) > article > div.yazi_bilgi").text;
 }

} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load photos');
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create custom `http.Client`, override it's `send` method and use it to send requests.
Example code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ClientWithUserAgent extends http.Client {

  final http.Client _client;

  ClientWithUserAgent(this._client);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) async {
    request.headers['User-Agent'] = 'user agent value';
    return _client.send(request);
  }

}
```

And then you will be able to use it like that:

```
final client = ClientWithUserAgent(http.Client());

final response = await client.get('some_url');
```

Also note that passing original `http.Client` to constructor allows to use composition of various client modifications like headers, logging etc.
If you don't need it you can instantiate `http.Client()` inside `ClientWithUserAgent`

Comment: since http: ^0.12.2 you should extend from BaseClient.

Answer (score 4):

Based on `http` package latest version [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/) you should extend `http.BaseClient`.
A code snipped directly copied from docs:

```dart
lass UserAgentClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final String userAgent;
  final http.Client _inner;

  UserAgentClient(this.userAgent, this._inner);

  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    request.headers['user-agent'] = userAgent;
    return _inner.send(request);
  }
}
```